# How to use error handling in Spring Boot 3.2.1?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to upgrade Spring Boot to version 3.2.1 and am running into this error. Version 3.2.0 causes the same error, but reverting back to our older version 3.1.5 allows for a successful build. Does anyone happen to know if there is a compatibility change needed for error handling in the new 3.2 versions? The maven dependency tree shows version 6.1.2 for the spring framework version. The following is the error message:

The import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandler cannot be resolvedJava(268435846)

I have tried checking spring boot and spring framework versions and they both appear to use the latest available. Spring boot 3.1.5 allows for a successful build but 3.2 does not. Also, Spring Kafka is on 3.1.1.